# Load page when user reaches the end of page minus x amount of pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I'm using to detect the end of a page. when it reaches the end it fires off a function that loads more content. This seems to work fine for me but for other users (that don't have as large of screen as I do) it's not working. I'm thinking it has something to do with a large table that is throwing everything off.

In any event, what I'm trying to do now is instead of loading at end of page, load at end of page -100 pixels or whatever amount of pixels i need. Here's my code:

```
win.scroll(function() {
    // End of the document reached?


    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var winHeight = win.height();
    var scTop = win.scrollTop();        

    if (docHeight - winHeight == scTop) {
        if(!allRecords){
            populateAssignments();
        }
    }
});
```

Now I tried different combinations of subtracting 100 from the docHeight or the winHeight or the scrollTop but nothing seems to work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really trust the users with scroll functions and `window.scroll` to fire at a certain time. You should use logical operators here. Try comparing if it's greater value:

```
if (docHeight - winHeight > scTop) {
```

That should work. Your first and different combinations might all be right. Only the logic here is flawed. Use the greater than operator.

Comment: so doHeight-100 is what you're saying? with the > of course :)